# Ergodicity of group action on a generating family

Tags: group-actions, ergodic-theory

Endow $\{0,1\}$ with the fair coin measure $\mu(\{0\})=1/2=\mu(\{1\})$, and consider the infinite product measure $m$ on $\mathcal{C}=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. The $\mathcal{C}$ can be seen as an abelian group under coordinatewise addition mod 2. Then, the set $Q$ of sequences with at most finitely many ones is a dense subgroup $\mathcal{C}$. I'd like to show that the action of $Q$ on $\mathcal{C}$ given by $x\mapsto x+q$, $q\in Q$ is ergodic with respect to the measure $m$, i.e. given a measurable set $E\subset \mathcal{C}$,

$$ \forall q\in Q(q+E=E)\implies m(E)=0 \vee m(E)=1.$$

This is easy to see for cylinder sets, so I tried to show that the collection of sets with this property, say $\mathcal{B}$, forms a $\sigma$-algebra. Its fairly straightforward to see that $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under complementation, but I do not see how to show that it is closed under countable unions.

If we take $B_n\in\mathcal{B}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $B=\bigcup_n B_n$, then the fact that $q+B=B$ for all $q\in Q$ does not necessarily mean that $q+B_n=B_n$ for every $n$ and every $q$, or at least the implication is not immediate.

Comment: This is really a special case of [Kolmogorov's zero-one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov's_zero%E2%80%93one_law).  Show that every invariant set $E$ is independent of itself, by first showing that $E$ is independent of all cylinder sets and then using the fact that every event in the product $\sigma$-algebra can be approximated by cylinder sets.

Comment: @Blackbird Thank you for your comment. I think I can do the approximation argument, but I'm not sure how to show that $m(C\cap E)=m(C)m(E)$ for a cylinder set $C$. It seem intuitively reasonable, since the $Q$ invariance points to the fact that $E$ does not depend on finitely many coordinates, but that's as far as I got.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the proof of the independence of $E$ from each cylinder set $C$ is also via approximation.  Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ be the base of $C$ (i.e., the set of coordinates on which $C$ depends).  Then, $C$ is independent of every cylinder set with base $J\subseteq\mathbb{N}\setminus I$.  The sub-$\sigma$-algebra of events not depending on $I$ is generated by the algebra of cylinder sets whose base is included in $\mathbb{N}\setminus I$.  Therefore, $E$ can be approximated by such cylinder sets.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general argument. Let $T$ be given by $T(\omega) = q+\omega$, and take $A$ such that $TA = A$. Take $\epsilon > 0$ and $I$, a finite union of disjoint cylinders so that $\mu(A\Delta I) < \epsilon$. Then, take $k$ large so that $\mu(T^k I \cap I) = \mu(I)^2$ (which is possible). Then, $\mu(A) = \mu(T^k A \cap A) \approx_\epsilon \mu(T^k I \cap I) = \mu(I)^2 \approx_\epsilon \mu(A)^2$. This implies (once you fill in the details), that $\mu(A) \in \{0,1\}$.